# assign a value to a variable basis on grep response

Tags: linux, grep, variable-assignment

I need to check for a substring in a string. If present then assign some value to FILE variable and if not present then assign some other value to same FILE variable.

Below is what I have tried:

```
FILE="$(hostname -f | grep ".dev." &&  echo "data.txt.pp" || echo "data.txt")"; echo $FILE
```

But in the output of $FILE variable:

```
hostname.corp.com data.txt.pp
```

I see hostname is also being printed out. I just want either `data.txt.pp` or `data.txt`. If hostname has `.dev.` in it then I want FILE variable to be `data.txt.pp` otherwise it should have `data.txt`. What is wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-q` :

```
hostname -f | grep -q "\.dev\." && echo "data.txt.pp" || echo "data.txt"
```

Avoid using UPPER CASE variables, they are reserved for system use